# Setting instance variable with same name as method parameter?

Tags: java

If I have code like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public int bar;

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Eclipse warns me that the assignment doesn't do anything (for obvious reasons). Can I fix it by changing it to `this.bar = bar;` or is it best to just use a different variable name?

Comment: `this.foo = foo;` is an accepted convention in a set method or constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `this.bar = bar;` is just fine. Most setters are coded this way.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to do something like that, one common course of action is to rename the function parameter.

```
public void setBar(int theBar) {
    bar = theBar;
}
```

If you would rather not do that, use `this.` prefix, like this:

```
this.bar = bar;
```

Comment: @azurefrog It is often a team decision, when the team decides on the common coding standards. I've seen it done both ways.

Comment: Thanks, this is for an assignment where we are given the method signatures so it's probably better for me to use `this` rather than changing it the parameter name.

Comment: @LionKing34 Parameter names are not part of a method signature, so you can freely change them.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight True, I meant we were given the Javadoc file which does have paremeter names.